# Populating Listbox with items from an array C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, listbox

I have created an array of string in an xaml file that I need to use as items in a c# wpf ListBox control.  I've tried all kinds of ways to get the items from the array to add to the ListBox, but to no avail.  Here's my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ArrayOfString xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <string>DocumentSettings.DepositRuntimeDefaults</string>
  <string>DocumentSettings.LendingCustomization.CommonSettings</string>
</ArrayOfString>
```

That's the array, now in my code behind I have a singleton that creates a list:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;

namespace csi.Framework.Business
{
    public class UIPathOptionsManager
    {
        public static UIPathOptionsManager Instance = new UIPathOptionsManager();

        public List<string> UIPathOptions;

        public string theUIPathOptionsFile { get; set; }

        public void Initialize(string theDirectory)
        {
            theUIPathOptionsFile = theDirectory + "\\UIPathOptions.xaml";
            if (File.Exists(theUIPathOptionsFile))
            {
                System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer xmlDeserializer = new
                System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(List<string>));
                TextReader fileReader = new StreamReader(theUIPathOptionsFile);
                UIPathOptions = (List<string>)xmlDeserializer.Deserialize(fileReader);
                fileReader.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And from there I have a ListBox class that I need to populate:

```
ListBox theUIPathOptionslistBox = new ListBox();
                theUIPathOptionslistBox.Items.Add();
                theUIPathOptionslistBox.TabIndex = nRow;
                theUIPathOptionslistBox.SelectionMode = SelectionMode.Multiple;
                theUIPathOptionslistBox.ClipToBounds = true;
                theUIPathOptionslistBox.Focusable = true;
                theUIPathOptionslistBox.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
                theUIPathOptionslistBox.Height = 24;
```

I'm really hoping someone out there can help me out - it feels like I should know this but....

Comment: Assign `UIPathOptions` to the `ItemsSource` property of the ListBox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assign  UIPathOptionsManager.Instance.UIPathOptions to ItemSource. Performed this in Window_Loaded Event.

```
UIPathOptionsManager.Instance.Initialize
(@"C:\Users\Administrator\source\repos\WpfApp9");

        ListBox theUIPathOptionslistBox = new ListBox();


        theUIPathOptionslistBox.ItemsSource = UIPathOptionsManager.Instance.UIPathOptions;


        theUIPathOptionslistBox.TabIndex = nRow;
        theUIPathOptionslistBox.SelectionMode = SelectionMode.Multiple;
        theUIPathOptionslistBox.ClipToBounds = true;
        theUIPathOptionslistBox.Focusable = true;
        theUIPathOptionslistBox.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
        theUIPathOptionslistBox.Height = 24;
```

You can also do this by creating a property and then use Binding.

Comment: Thanks Satish, I've flagged your response as the answer - much appreciated!